# Scaling issue in liblas / cloudcompare

Tags: utm, liblas, cloudcompare

I'm facing problems exporting a pointcloud in geo-coordinates in my software. I'm using liblas to export the point data.

I have GeoData to display but upon loading it I subtract an offset to keepo the values low.
Initially when exporting I set the scale and offset in the `liblas::Header` to 1e-4 scale and 0 offset (for testing only). This gives me a decent, quite dense point cloud (see first screenshot below). 
Now I'm experimenting with exporting to the global coordinate system, so I set the scale to 1 (my coordinates are in meters) and the offset to the offset with respect to the UTM coordinate system, so some value like (354000,5403000,400).

In CloudCompare the right sale/offset is shown and the point cloud looks reasonable. However, It's displayed really sparse (second screenshot). Any ideas where this might come from? Could it be an issue when exporting or a loss of exactness in CloudCompare? The number of points / point cloud size in MB is exactly the same.

[image: dense point cloud]
[image: sparse point cloud]

Answer (score 1):

My error was misunderstanding the offset and scale functionality in liblas.

When defining an offset and a scale the adaptation of the points is performed inside the liblas::Point::SetCoordinates function.

The trick is to set the offset and scale in the header of the writer but still give the SetCoordinates function the original values.

Also the scale parameter defines the precision, so it's important to choose it reasonably low.